# Is it possible to multiplayer Project Zomboid with only one copy of the game?

Tags: gog, project-zomboid

See, I have a few friends coming over for a LAN party, and I want a game to play together, but I'm a poor student. Is it possible to use the GOG copy of the game to play together on LAN? It's really not possible for us to shell out the money needed for 6 copies and we only want to play it for one night. In addition, I'm not going to share the game with the friends, and I'll delete it after the night.

I'm more concerned with technical feasibility, rather than legal feasibility, since I live out of US jurisdiction in a country that doesn't tend to prosecute such crimes. I've nothing but respect for the creators of Project Zomboid, but financially, I don't have the money to purchase 6 copies, and I think that playing a single night with friends, would fall under the "watching movies together" metaphor outlined in GOG's FAQ.

Answer (score 13):

While the game itself may be free of DRM, [GOG.COM policies do not allow it](https://support.gog.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001942753-FAQ-Downloads-and-streaming)

> Can I enjoy my purchases both on my laptop and desktop computer at
>   home?
>
> Yes. We do not limit the number of installations or reinstallations,
>   as long as you install your purchased games on computers in your
>   household. So yeah, if you've got a render-farm in the basement, you
>   might actually break the world record for the number of legal Witcher
>   installations in one household. **However, if you think about installing
>   your game on a friend's machine or sharing it with others then please
>   don't do it, okay?**  The same principle applies to movies - you're free
>   to watch them anywhere you want, with anyone you want, as long as you
>   don't share them with people who haven't purchased them.

Emphasis mine